# Laravel 5: How to group a collection dynamically by one column or another depending on item's column value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I have a collection of items as a result of an Eloquent model query. What I need to do is to somehow group the items of that collection either by one column or another depending on a specific item's field value if it satisfies a condition. Is it possible to use a function inside the `groupBy()` or there is another way to do this, if possible at all? I'll provide additional details if needed in case there is a theoretical solution for such situation.

Update:

Here is the code where I create two separate collections and then group each of them:

```
...

// First collection which is grouped by grouping_field1
$non_grouped_products = Product::with("some_relation")
    ->whereHas("some_relation", function($q) {
        $q->where("conditional_field", 0)
            ->where("some_field1", 1)
            ->orWhere("some_field2", 0);
    })->where("some_field3", "some_value")
    ->where("some_field4", "some_value2")
    ->get()
    ->groupBy("grouping_field1");

// Second collection which is grouped by grouping_field2
$products = Product::with("some_relation")
    ->whereHas("some_relation", function($q) {
        $q->where("conditional_field", 1)
            ->where("some_field1", 1)
            ->orWhere("some_field2", 0);
    })->where("some_field3", "some_value")
    ->where("some_field4", "some_value2")
    ->get()
    ->groupBy("grouping_field2");

$all_products = [];

// Here is where I join the collections
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $all_products[$key] = $product;
}
foreach ($non_grouped_products as $key => $product) {
    $all_products[$key] = $product;
}

$merged_collection = new Collection($all_products);

...
```

Why I need to avoid making two collections is because I want to make an `orderBy()` just once instead of doing it separately on each of initial collections as after merging the ordering is not correct anymore.
I need to check the value of the `conditional_field` and if it satisfies one or another condition, I need to group the item by one of the grouping fields.

I hope I was explicit enough. If you need some other details, I'll provide them to you so it will be easier for you to understand all the circumstances and what specifically I need to achieve. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Show us code, what you want to do ! We will surely help with that

Comment: I've edited the question by adding some code and details regarding my problem.

Comment: ->groupBy("grouping_field2");
wirte it before get , you wrote after get

Comment: The idea is that I want to keep the group by value as a key for collection items, that's the point of grouping. If to put `groupBy()` before creating the collection out of the items retrieved from the model, it just won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [the docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_groupBy), the groupBy function's first param is a callable | string. So yes it is possible but we can only help if you post the code

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question with the code and some explanations. :)